# Resetting SMSC for Lollipop 5 SMS bug

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sms, settings, bugs

Ok, so I tried to do this [tutorial](http://www.techlegends.in/how-to-fix-the-sms-bug-on-android-5-0-lollipop/) to fix the SMS bug that was keeping me from texting my buddy in Switzerland (I'm in the US using AT&T on a Samsung Galaxy s6 Edge with Lollipop v5.0.2);

I followed it, did the `*#*#4636#*#*` and brought up the screen. Hit "Refresh" and it displays `"1",0`

So I hit update "Update" and reboot. Now not only does my texts to him fail, but all the local US people I can normally msg fine fails as well. Could someone show me the light? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble. I'm the writer of that fix. Well, I was able to get it right on Nexus 5, Unite 2, Galaxy S5, LG G2, LG G3 and MOTO G as well. So, if you've come across a different problem try doing a factory reset. And, keep a backup of your data before formatting it.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it resolved via at&t support although I couldn't tell what they technically did to resolve it. Cheers!

Comment: Great! And sorry again haha.. Do check out our site more often (if you like the content). We're students so can't really update 24x7 content :-D